# How to set Django-Crispy-Forms multiple fields in one line?

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to set multiple fields in one line with Django Crispy Forms but it's not working.

Here's what I got:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import *
from crispy_forms.layout import *
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import *

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    mins = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(0, 60)])
    hrs = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(0, 24)])
    month = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 13)])
    weeks = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(0, 7)])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout( 
            Div(
                Div('mins',css_class='col-md-6',),
                Div('hrs',css_class='col-md-6',),
                Div('month',css_class='col-md-6',),
                Div('weeks',css_class='col-md-6',),
                css_class='row',
            ),

            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit'),
            ),
        )
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting each one of your fields with `col-md-6`. If the element which encloses your form is not big enough then the fields will come in different row.